# HTML: keeping the middle of an image alligned with the middle of the page

Tags: html

I have a banner that I want to keep the middle of the image inline with the middle of the page. The problem is when I re-size the page smaller it doesn't push the image off the left and the middle of the image slides off to the right.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
    <img src="bannerr.png">
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to change the behaviour, is there a way to auto cut off the left side to keep it in the middle?

Comment: How do you set the body style properties, would you mind show them all?

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in CSS

```
   img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; }
```

If you need html only, try this

```
<img src="bannerr.png" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;">
```

edit: added position:relative above

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply however the behavior still remains the same

Comment: @codehorse But if he puts on the css, it will affect all the images. Wouldn't it be better to create a class for that ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I fixed it by adding it into a column :)
I think I didn't describe the problem properly

Answer (score 0):

This is old HTML 4 but you could use the `<center>` tag around the `<div>` and do this.

```
<center>
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
    <img src="bannerr.png">
</div>
</center>
```